# Como customizar log do tomcat no spring boot ?

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, log

estou com um pequeno problema com minha aplicação, o log do meu tomcat está gerando uma quantidade meio grande de dados, e isto está deixando a aplicaçao da empresa meio lenta, gostaria de saber se tem algum modo de diminuir a quantidade de log, em outras palavras, se há como customizar este log para produzir apenas os dados que nós achamos pertinentes, ou então alguma opção para resumir o log, apenas exibindo o que é realmente relevante, espero ter sido claro
Desde já agradeço a todos

Answer (score 1):

Você pode alterar a quantidade de log no arquivo **application.properties**.

Normalmente, quando eu estou em desenvolvimento eu deixo **DEBUG** e quando esta em produção eu deixo **ERROR**.

```
logging.level.=ERROR
```

[Spring Boot Log Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-logging-format)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o Log4J, é uma biblioteca muito simples que consegue gerenciar a criação de arquivos de logs, você pode criar arquivos para tipos de logs específicos. Há diversos tutoriais na web, em pouquíssimo tempo você consegue contornar o seu problema.
[Site e tutorial que pode te ajudar](https://springframework.guru/using-log4j-2-spring-boot/)